# JPA implementations suitable for the case

Tags: java, jpa

I am building a web application using JSF 2.0 tomcat 7.0.20 and a MySQL DB, My application is for a small company actully starting its business.

Now I see that there is Many implementations of JPA 2.0, now in my Case which one would be the most suitable ? or should I use pure JPA 2.0 and create my own implementation?

I want somting that would work best for the company now and wouldn't make trouble when it grows in the future, i was considering Hibernate or do you have another suggestion?

Answer (score 2):

The following former questions will give you some insight about the pro and cons for each JPA implementation, and choose the one which is the best for your company.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2569522/hibernate-or-eclipselink

[JPA 2.0 Implementations comparison : Hibernate 3.5 vs EclipseLink 2 vs OpenJPA 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3035308/jpa-2-0-implementations-comparison-hibernate-3-5-vs-eclipselink-2-vs-openjpa-2)

I believe that Hibernate is actually more popular nowadays, and many industries are using Hibernate.

Answer (score 0):

Depends how you want to judge "most suitable" ... license? most users? fewer known bugs?. Most used doesn't necessarily mean most reliable, but then it can mean there are more people who understand its problem areas and how to avoid them. All would likely do the job for many applications, though some have long-standing issues. [DataNucleus JPA](http://www.datanucleus.org) is another choice for you to consider, providing for all that you need there but also allowing much more flexibility than others in terms of input and in terms of which datastores you can persist to, should these be factors in your application.